# Inverse Transform Sampling and the RV itself; Independence

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X$ be a positive continuous random variable with CDF $F\left(x\right)$. Then from Inverse Transform Sampling, we know $F\left(X\right)\sim Unif(0,1)$.

So, are $X$ and $F\left(X\right)$ independent, since $F\left(X\right)\sim Unif(0,1)$? Set $Y=F\left(X\right)$, and we compute the joint distribution $F_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)$.

\begin{align*}
F_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right) & =\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq x,\quad Y\leq y\right)\\
 & =\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq x,\quad F\left(X\right)\leq y\right)\\
 & =\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq x,X\leq F^{-1}\left(y\right)\right)\\
 & =\begin{cases}
F\left(x\right), & x<F^{-1}\left(y\right)\iff y>F\left(x\right);\\
y, & x\geq F^{-1}\left(y\right)\iff y\leq F\left(x\right).
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
It doesn't quite separate into $F\left(x\right)$ and $F\left(y\right)=y,\quad y\in\left[0,1\right]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, $F(X)$ depends on $X$ so there's no reason to think they are independent.  Formally, for $F$ invertible,

$$P(X\leq x, F(X)\leq y)=P(X\leq x, X\leq F^{-1}(y))=P(X\leq \min\{x,F^{-1}(y)\})=F(\min\{x,F^{-1}(y)\}),$$

which is not the same as $$P(X\leq x)P(F(X)\leq y)=F(x)y.$$

Answer (score 0):

$X$ and $F(X)$ are not independent. For example, consider $X \sim \mathrm{N}(0,1)$. In this case,
$$\mathrm{P}(X\leq 0) = \mathrm{P}(X\leq0,F(X)\leq0.5).$$
Since $F(X) \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$, it holds $\mathrm{P}(F(X)\leq 0.5) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $X$ and $F(X)$ and not independent.